# Group list of numbers into groups based on the range from the lowest number

Tags: scala

Assuming there the list of numbers and a range value, I want to group them into groups, in which the item in each group is within the range from the lowest number, and sort them.

For example, I have a list `val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and the range `val range = 2`. Then, I'm looking for a way to output the following result: `result = List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,9), List(10))`. Which means if `range = 0` then only identical numbers are in the same group.

At the moment, I use the following method

```
val minVal = l.min
val range1 = (minVal + range).toDouble
val groups = l.foldLeft(Map[Int, List[Int]]())((result, num) => {
    val numRange = math.ceil(num / range1).toInt
    if (result.contains(numRange)) {
        result.updated(numRange, num :: result(numRange))
    } else {
        result.updated(numRange, List(num))
    }
})
groups.keys.toList.sortBy(k => k).map(groups(_))
```

It works in most cases except when `range = 0` and `slowestNum != 1`. E.g. for the list `val l = List(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and the range `val range = 2`, the result is `List(List(2), List(4, 3), List(6, 5), List(8, 7), List(10, 9))`.

So, I wonder if there is any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't get very well the idea of the range. For example, if your list contains two equal numbers and your range is 0, those two equal numbers wouldn't end in the same group?

Comment: @kaktusito thanks, I've updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: I have gotten a great idea how to do it nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Why complicate?

```
def coll(l: List[Int], range: Int): List[List[Int]] =
    if (l.isEmpty) Nil else {
        val (b, a) = l.span((l.head - range to l.head + range).contains)
        b :: coll(a, range)
    }
```

So, this algorithm collects numbers into a group until the number are in the plus/minus range.

```
val list = List(7,4,1,9,10,20,50,52,30)
coll(list, 3)
res6: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7, 4), List(1), List(9, 10), List(20), List(50, 52), List(30))
```

If you want each group by itself sorted, then call `res6.map(_.sorted)`.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally do something like this:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val range = 2

val result = l.sorted.foldLeft(List[List[Int]]()) {
  (cur, x) =>
    if ((cur nonEmpty) && x - cur.head.last <= range) (x :: cur.head) :: cur.tail
    else List(x) :: cur
}
```

although there may be some clever and neat ways. Of course, you can always do if you want the result ordered:

```
val ret = result.reverse.map(_.reverse)
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
val groupedList = l.map(i => l.filter(s => s >= i && s - i <= range))

groupedList.foldLeft(List(groupedList.head)) {
      case (r, c) => if (r.last.last < c.head) r ++ List(c) else r
 }
```

For range 2

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val range = 2                                   
val groupedList = l.map(i => l.filter(s => s >= i && s - i <= range))
groupedList.foldLeft(List(groupedList.head)) {
case (r, c) => if (r.last.last < c.head) r ++ List(c) else r
}                                               
//> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10))
```

For range 0

```
 val l = List(1,1,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
 val range = 0                                  
val groupedList = l.map(i => l.filter(s => s >= i && s - i <= range))
groupedList.foldLeft(List(groupedList.head)) {
case (r, c) => if (r.last.last < c.head) r ++ List(c) else r
}                                              
 //> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1), List(2), List(3), List(4), List(5), List(6), List(7), List(8), List(9), List(10))
```